# StartCoroutine function not working on android, but works fine in Unity editor

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I am building simple user data-retrieve function from web service (`WWW`). I can't solve this, so maybe you guys can help me out?

I am using `StartCoroutine` method. When I build and run on my android device (android 6.0.1), I click button and it does nothing! Absolutely nothing! However, in Unity editor, it's working perfectly!

I searched for more information about this issue and someone recommended me a plugin called **"More Effective Coroutines"**. http://trinary.tech/category/mec/ Well by now you probably get the idea that this plugin ain't helped me at all!

**Here's my C# code with plugin (i commented out standard Unity code):**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
//using "More Effective Coroutines" plugin:
using MovementEffects;
public class Login : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField LoginUsername;
    private string usernameInput;

    public InputField LoginPassword;
    private string passwordInput;

    string connectionLink = "00.00.00.211/app/login.php";

    public Text conResponse;

    public void OnSubmit(){

        usernameInput = LoginUsername.text;
        passwordInput = LoginPassword.text;

        //DEFAULT: StartCoroutine (Login(usernameInput, passwordInput));
        Timing.RunCoroutine(_login(usernameInput, passwordInput));
    }

    //DEFAULT: IEnumerator login(string username, string password){
    IEnumerator<float> _login(string username, string password){

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();

        form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
        form.AddField("passwordPost", password);

        WWW www = new WWW(connectionLink, form);

        //DEFAULT: yield return www;
        yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(1f);

        if (www.text == "ok") {

            SceneManager.LoadScene ("inGame", LoadSceneMode.Single);

        } else {

            conResponse.text = www.text;

            switch (www.text) {
                case"noUser":
                    conResponse.text = "User "+username+" not found in database!";
                    break;

                case"loginFailed":
                    conResponse.text = "Check your password and try again!";
                    break;
            }

            Debug.LogWarning(www.text);

        }
    }
}
```

Please take a look and give me a feedback what I'm doing wrong? C# is my new language.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Are you sure that `OnSubmit()` is being called on Android? I mean, if you add a Debug.Log("OnSubmit clicked "); or something like that, you are able to see that in the console (ie, logcat)?

Comment: @mayo yes, its being called on Android.

Comment: What is `connectionLink`? If `00.00.00.211` is the address of your local machine, the build on Android will try to reach the 'android' local machine.. unless you have your server running on your cellphone the app will not be able to create a connection...

Comment: @mayo it's actually domain, but i have changed it to random numerals. Let's say its: `domain.com`

Comment: that's it!!! i have added `https://` and it works!! Damn!

Comment: opps :/
is the result of StartCoroutine null?, I mean:  `var coroutine = StartCoroutine(login(usernameInput, passwordInput)); Debug.Log("Cr is null? " + (coroutine == null) );` ??

Comment: Oh !! cool ! haha !

Comment: Btw is weird that you weren't printing any error. Try to have an structure that prints the result of your operation in case of errors. like `if (www.error != null) { //do something/ ...`,

Answer (score 2):

I found out why it's not working on mobile with the help of @mayo!

I just forgot to add `https://` at the start of address:

`string connectionLink = "https://00.00.00.211/app/login.php";`

Hope someone else will get this useful!

Comment: That's true, because on Windows you don't need that - it'll add automatically, but android devices no.